# Google Play App Signing Process

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

Following image completely explain for what point I am asking:

[image]

What is the difference between CONTINUE, OPT-OUT and REUSE SIGNING KEY options?

Also what option shall I require to select for easy process? so that I got experience as like before because before this kind of steps not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the [documentation is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

In short:

- CONTINUE means Google will sign your app for you, and look after the security, backup etc. This is what I'd recommend for a simple safe process.
- OPT-OUT means you want to sign your app yourself. This runs the risk of you not being able to update your app if you lose your signing key (or get it compromised).
- REUSE SIGNING KEY means Google will sign the app for you, but will use the *same* key you already use to sign another app. This is needed in certain rare instances where apps share code. If you don't understand why you'd need this, then you almost certainly don't need it.